# To restrict ShowWindow() of dialog

Tags: winapi, mfc, windows-ce

i have one dialog box in MFC(Wince platform),and one list box over it. I need to spawn a thread after dialog box become visible. But some times it seems like the thread is started before complete execution of ShowWindow(). How i can restrict the the execution of thread untill Dialog box fully visible on screen.

Regards,

Mukesh

Comment: `ShowWindow` is not used for dialog boxes.

Comment: but its working... as for my knowledge dialog box is alos kind of window its nt specific to any window. show window will work for all kind of sub window as well. like (buttons,list,editbox , etc)

Comment: Well really, for starters, you shouldn't be using `ShowWindow` at all if you're using MFC. But a "dialog box" generally refers to a *modal dialog*, in which case you would use `DoModal` in MFC.

Comment: i have dialog box, and over it there is list box.. and that dialog box is modal less dialog. so i am hiding and showing the dialog box on some button click event. so thats why just after showing the the window i need to start one thread for another drwaing..

Comment: You really shouldn't do your drawing in another thread. All UI operations, including populating controls and showing windows, should be confined to the UI thread.

Comment: If you have to do your drawing in another thread, at least draw onto a memory DC that you blit over to the window DC in your main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a second thread to do drawing (as others have said).

If you want to update the window when an action occurs in another thread, then in the other thread invalidate the window to force a repaint, then when the repaint occurs update the window with whatever new values there are. This way you wont have to do any of the horrible synchronizing of paint operations that you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to spawn a thread when the dialog gets activated for the first time. You would need to use one of those WM_ACTIVATE message

Comment: hmm ok but its not like that .. dialog box is creating for one time. i am using modal less dialog . which i have already created in memory. so on button click i need show and hide the window. so its like on one button click show the window and start the thread, and on other button click hide the window and then stop the thread.
so for stop button its wrking fine, but while start button thread started before completion ShowWindow() call

Answer (score 0):

To be absolutely sure that the thread starts at the same time the dialog becomes visible, just start the thread as the last thing you do the first time WM_PAINT is processed.

Comment: Thanks codebolt , you mean to say i need to call start thread as last statement in OnPaint() function... is it ?

Comment: Yes, but you should only do it one time (OnPaint will be called many times). So make a test to see if you have already started the thread.